# Inserir data actual em Base de Dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, data

Eu tenho um base de dados com uma **table Noticias** com:

- Id (Primary key e auto_increment)
- Noticia (varchar, onde escrevo a noticia)
- Data(onde tem que estar a data actual, apenas dd/mm/yyyy)

mas eu nunca mexi com datas e não sei como inserir na BD com **PHP**.

Alguém sabe algo sobre isto que me podia ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na base de dados, assumo que seja MYSQL, podes usar o tipo de dados [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) para guardar esta informação. Eu definiria a tabela assim:

```
CREATE TABLE Noticias (
    id      INT,
    Noticia NVARCHAR(25000),
    Data    DATE
)
```

Para guardar a data actual tens duas alternativas, podes fazer isso directamente na base de dados, no momento do INSERT usando a função CURDATE();

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Noticias` ('Id', 'Noticia', 'Data') VALUES ('1', 'Noticia de ultima hora', CURDATE())");
```

Se preferires podes fazer no PHP da seguinte forma:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Noticias` (`Id`, `Noticia`, `data`) VALUES ('$id', '$noticia' '$date')");
```

Em relação ao formato da data. Eu sugeriria guardar no formato YYYY-MM-DD e depois, no select para obter os dados, podes formatar a data de acordo com a tua preferência do seguinte modo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Data, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM Noticias
```

Caso pretendas mesmo assim guardar no formato indicado, podes fazer o seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO Noticias VALUES 
(1, 'Texto da noticia', STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: Mas e na base de dados qual deve ser o tipo do campo data?

Comment: è isso mesmo muito Obrigado! Mas aparece ano/mês/dia, e eu precisava que  mostrasse dia/mês/ano